# How does the MetadataType attribute mark a class as a validation class in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I have my ADO entity generated in MVC 2 and I know that if I want to put custom validation on an object I can do something like this.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntity_Validation))]
public partial class MyEntity
{
    private sealed class MyEntity_Validation
    {
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z][0-9]{5}")]
        public string SomeField{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

But I don't know why that works.

How does that work? Some sort of convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata is a convention, yes.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx.  You can add attributes to fields to enforce validation, display, concurrency, all sorts of common usefulness.  Hope this helps.